# CSS background image path translated different in production environment?

Tags: html, css, iis

Here is our website structure

```
main application
   sub application (index file using css is located here)
      content
         assets
            css (CSS file located here)
            images (image located here)
```

In the css file we are using a bacground image with a relative url like this:

```
background: #ffffff url("../images/bodybg.png") repeat;
```

So it tells css to find the image one level up in images folder

This works on our local machines with IIS. This is translated to:

```
http://localhost/subapplication/content/assets/images/bodybg.png
```

However in our production environment also on IIS this is translated to:

```
https://www.oursite.com/images/bodybg.png
```

I tried changing to a root relative path:

```
background: #ffffff url("/subapplication/content/assets/images/bodybg.png") repeat;
```

This fixed the problem but does anyone know why the relative css path had two results on two environments?

Comment: Is the CSS file actually loaded from that location? (You can check the css url in chrome developer tools)

Comment: Good point. It seems that the way we are using bundling in ASP.NET MVC 5 is causing this. I'll update the questioan with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the way we are using bundling in ASP.NET MVC 5 is causing this.

In the production index file it is written like this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/main")
```

And in bundleconfig:

```
 bundles
     .Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/main")
                    .Include("~/Content/assets/css/main.css",
```

that translates to using a root relative path in the code index file :

```
/subapplication/Content/main?v=12341234lmkelmk
```

I need to render the bundle to where the actual css is located to make relative paths work, like this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/main/assets/css/main")

 bundles
         .Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/main/assets/css/main")
                        .Include("~/Content/assets/css/main.css",
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is relative to the environment.
You might have sub domains/virtual directories also which are messing the relativity.

Comment: To clarify. The structure (folder, virtual directories) of the site is the same and there is no use of subdomains in this case. But you are correct something is messing up the relativity here.